# WPF detach gridview header from body

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have a GridView inside a ListView, and I would like to detach the header from the body, so I can put a border around each one separately like so:

[image]

Can I achieve this with the templating options already available in WPF? It seems like I can only customize each header item but not the entire header as a single unit.

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a custom view, just style the existing GridView.

Comment: It doesn't help me style the entire header though, I can for example set a background color to "col1" and "col2", but how can I add a border around the entire header and detach it from the body?

Comment: Just a sec, I'll create an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to create your own styles and templates for the control. Here I've created a copy of the ListView style that ignores the border property and uses a custom ScrollViewer style:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
    <Style x:Key="CustomListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF042271"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{DynamicResource CustomScrollViewerStyle}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The ScrollViewer style adds the borders in the correct places:

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10"
                                    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                    BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
                                <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Columns="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="2,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                    BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                        <DockPanel Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar}" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="False" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="White" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Width="1"/>
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="White" Height="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

With my example:

```
        <ListView BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" Style="{StaticResource CustomListViewStyle}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Bob"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="LastName">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Bobson" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
```

Produces:

[image]

This is a good resource:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, take a look at Blend if you're setting styles. It was a real pain trying to work out all the parts but in Blend you can just "create copy of style" then fiddle with it to your hearts content.

If you're not on Win 7, then the style you copy will be what you're seeing in your application (unless you're using a style pack like MahApp.Metro or Material Design for XAML, in which case it should copy their styles).

It might just be easier to just create your own custom look!

Comment: It seems like the border is sticking to the header and body, can I not make it so that it's "around" them like in my example? I didn't mean border quite in the technical sense. I also will have separate borders for each header item, and another for the whole header.

I really appreciate the example code though, I will try to use this as a basis and see if I can achieve what I need with it. Thank you.

Comment: I think the thing that needs to be templated is the ScrollViewer, as that's the object that hosts "ScrollContentPresenter" with the content and the GridViewHeaderRowPresenter in a DockPanel. (Check out the visual tree of components in the debug black bar at the top of windows).

Comment: Worked out a better example, see edit (everything changed pretty much).

Comment: Thanks Joe, this works! I can achieve the border I want by adding padding and corner radius to the border. Will mark this as the answer.